# Ошибка "отладчику не удалось обнаружить исходный файл"

Tags: c#, asp.net, юнит-тесты, .net

Я тестирую класс. В него временно для отладки внёс изменения (1 строку).
При запуске теста в режиме отладки появляется ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(пути зачеркнул из-за соображения ИБ.)

файл по всем путям существует (путь, указанный в ошибке, существует)

Видимо только что собранный отлаживаемый файл сравнивается с последним собранным до внесения изменений — возможно тут я ошибаюсь и до конце механизм не понимаю — что происходит в этот момент.

Пробовал добавлять безопасную строку типа

```
var a1 = 1;
```

вставлять её в разные места (конструктор, метод) — ничего не меняется

Ошибка происходит только в данном проекте, в другом проекте такой проходит нормально

в stackoverflow ничего не нашёл. Подскажите, как решить ошибку?

Comment: За все время работы со студией и отладкой я понял лишь одно: когда студия говорит, что чего-то не хватает, значит этого не хватает. Если файла нет, значит его там точно нет. Никакой магии. Весь вопрос в том, правильный ли путь, все ли пиксели в буквах пути на своих местах?

Comment: я проверил, 100% файл на месте, тщательно проверил имя, путь копировал из ошибки убеждался в проводнике. по всем путям (они одинаковые в ошибке)

Comment: проверил по Git, вдруг случайно удалил - всё ок

Comment: `В него временно для отладки внёс изменения (1 строку).` - а если не вносить? Может контрольная сумма не совпадает.

Comment: если не вносить - всё нормально. но мне надо внести

Comment: вроде заработало вчера, сейчас стало опять глючить, по другой причине - не срабатывает точка останова на тесте, а переходит сразу в метод

Comment: Проверьте галочку "оптимизировать код" - опция компилятора. Если она стоит, то отладка будет затруднена.

Comment: @aeport спасибо